# $\{(x,y): x, y \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is closed??

Tags: general-topology

Is the set $\{(x,y): x, y \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ open, closed, both, or neither?
My believe is that this is a closed set. However, I do not know how to prove it. Can someone give some light into this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Open/closed in which space?
Which definitions of "open" and "closed" do you prefer?  Whichever ones you choose are likely to be quite straightforward to check.

Comment: I'll assume you are using the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Hint: what limit points does your set have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likewise @Boris, I assume your topology is the usual one. Now use this fact that $\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb R$ has no any limit point in $\mathbb R$. In fact if $a\in\mathbb R$, we can find (or choose) $\delta>0$ so small that $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\cap\mathbb Z=\{a\}$.

Comment: Nice example/illustration!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the usual topology of the plane, then $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is closed, e.g., since  $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})\setminus(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The union of a locally finite collection of closed sets is closed.